# Почему не массив возвращается(как исправить ошибки)

Tags: php, отладка

```
<?php
var_dump(json_decode($_COOKIE['history_lots']));
if (isset($_GET['tab']) and $_GET['tab'] == 'lot' and !in_array($_GET['id_lot'], json_decode($_COOKIE['history_lots']))){
    setcookie('history_lots', json_encode((json_decode($_COOKIE['history_lots']))[] = $_GET['id_lot']), strtotime('next year'), '/');
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если в переводчик закинуть текст - то что пишет? хотя бы по первой ошибке

Comment: кстати json_decode принимает ещё второй параметр, чтобы в массив конвертировать....а не в объект

Comment: пробовал, не работает

Comment: что не работает?

Comment: переводчик не работает?

Comment: переводчик работает(я проверил со строкой)

Comment: и что переводчик пишет?

Comment: массив дает, но конкретно в этом  месте он не хочет массив давать

Comment: кто даёт массив? переводчик? ещё раз, с начала: "если в переводчик закинуть текст - то что пишет?"

Comment: var_dump(json_decode('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}', true));

Comment: array(5) { ["a"]=> int(1) ["b"]=> int(2) ["c"]=> int(3) ["d"]=> int(4) ["e"]=> int(5) }

Comment: Это вам переводчик так перевёл  текст ошибки?

Comment: я подумал что перводчик это  json_decode а не гугл переводчик(я тугодум)

Comment: я так и не понял почему не работает

Comment: ну на вопрос мой не был дан ответ, поэтому чего ждёте - не знаю ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MrIngo вы разобрались?

Answer (score 0):

Пока вы разбираетесь с переводчиком, дам вам полезный совет как работать с суперглобальными массивами.

Не используйте суперглобальные массивы как переменные. Не передавайте их в функции, не сравнивайте их. Всегда создавайте переменную, которой присваивайте  значение из суперглобального массива и дальше работайте только с этой переменной.

Присваивать удобно с помощью [оператора объединения с null](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce):

```php
$tab = $_GET['tab']?? '';
if ($tab === 'lot' ...) {...}
```

Этот простой приём позволит вам избежать множества глупых ошибок (например, что случится, если кук ещё нет?).

```php
<?php

$historyLotsJson = $_COOKIE['history_lots']?? '[]';
var_dump($historyLotsJson); // интереснее взглянуть, что там за json
$historyLots = json_decode($historyLots);

$tab = $_GET['tab']?? '';
$idLot = $_GET['id_lot']?? '';
if ($tab === 'lot' and !in_array($idLot, $historyLots)) {
    $historyLots[] = $idLot;
    setcookie('history_lots', json_encode($historyLots), strtotime('next year'), '/');
}
```

Видите? Переменные делают ваш код проще. Даже если в коде или в данных будет ошибка, разобраться с проблемой будет легче.

Comment: `??`  --- это **НЕ** тернарный оператор ................ `$historyLotsJson = $_COOKIE['history_lots']?? '[]';` --- и в результате у автора опять же ничего не выйдет.. потому что у него изначально не json там.  и `??`  никак не поможет в случае хоть пустой строки, хоть какой-либо....вообще не знаю что вы этим хотели сделать :))

Comment: Ну "теранрный" это упрощение. Сейчас поправлю. А что там в куке я не знаю. Сейчас 0, а перезагрузит страницу будет ещё что-то. Я хотел показать, что один раз разобравшись со значением из суперглобального массива можно дальше работать с переменной и не переживать каждый раз, что значения с ключом в массиве может и не быть. Ну а с переводом, я надеюсь, автор справится и в куке будет массив.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а вы не пользуетесь таким приёмом? Например куки у нас пока нет. У меня  по умолчанию там будет json, который распарсится в пустой массив. А вы бы как писали?

Comment: Просто `??` работает с `null`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский с null и несуществующим ключом. `$foo = []; $bar = $foo['bar']?? 'bar';` тоже нормально отработает.